# Grails result set pagination

Tags: grails, groovy, pagination, grails-orm

Suppose I have a class `User` with many `Customers` (marked with `hasMany` property).
In the class `Customer` I mark the owner with `belongsTo`.

Now when I want to get user's customers I simply write `User.read(params.id).customers`

I want a pagination in my test project, so reading the entire customer list doesnt make much sense.. I'd use something like `Customer.findAllByOwner` but this method is such a method is not present..

How do I limit the result set of such a query then (offset and limit)?

---

```
package myapp

class User {
    ...
    static hasMany = [customers: Customer]
    ...
}

package myapp

class Customer {
    ...
    static belongsTo = User
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Customer class here? Customer.findAllByOwner should be working.

Comment: findAllByOwner would imply Customer has an *owner* property, Dan Woods seems to have more what you're getting at, findAllByUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the idea in its most simplistic form here is that you want to get a list of Customers based off of the User object.

In that case, change your Customer domain class to something like...

```
class Customer {
   ...
   static belongsTo = [user: User]
   ...
}
```

Then, in your controller you can do something like:

```
def customerInstanceList = Customer.findAllByUser(User.get(params.id), [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This sound nice, but doesn't fetching a user (`User.get..`) each time I want the customers add an unnecessary overhead?

Comment: Secondly, can I use the `User` stored in the session i.e. `findAllByUser(session.user)` ?

Comment: Sure, if you have the User object in the session, then there's no need to re-fetch it; I would think that the fetch for User would have minimal impact since it would be an indexed retrieval, but it would of course depend on your data set, so you'd have to do your own tests to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the property in the Customer that you are trying to access is 'user' instead of 'owner'. If you want the property name to be owner it should be:

```
static belongsTo = [owner : User]
```

You can paginate the result set of a dynamic finder by supplying a map containing the pagination parameters as the final parameter.

```
def customers = Customer.findAllByOwner(user, [max:params.max, 
                                     offset:params.offset)
```

Comment: I get `No property found for name [owner] for class [class myapp.Customer]` error when trying